# Как получить access token instagram?

Tags: api, access, instagram, token

В прошлом году получил токен без проблем с помощью ссылки вида:
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[id]&redirect_uri=[site.ru]&response_type=token

Сейчас на другом аккаунте сделал все точно также, но получаю ошибку ?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.

PS вернулся на старый акк и сделал точно такие же действия и без проблем получил новый токен! А сейчас появляется окно с запросом на авторизацию и после нажатия на "авторизовать" я получаю ошибку.

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: Попробуйте получить новый токен так: [https://active-vision.ru/blog/fotografii-iz-instagram-api/](https://active-vision.ru/blog/fotografii-iz-instagram-api/)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449162/https-api-instagram-com-oauth-authorize-api-login-error

Тут была уже такая проблема!
в кратце - нужно просто **добавить в конце url параметр: &hl=en**